# Why do I Get Null Error When Checking if(a!=null)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

When I try to  if (productVariantViewModels != null) returns a null error. I don't understand why this happens? .net framework 4.6 a cshtml page

Edit.cshtml:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Edit";

List<ProductVariantViewModel> productVariantViewModels = ViewBag.ProductVariantViewModels;
}

...
...
...

                               
 if (productVariantViewModels != null)
 {
     foreach (var item in productVariantViewModels)
     {

        ...

     }
 }
```

Also ProductVariantViewModel:

```
   public class ProductVariantViewModel
{
    public Products Product { get; set; }
    public string VariantName { get; set; }
    public Variant Variant { get; set; }
    public List<ProductAttribute> VariantAttributes { get; set; }
    public List<string> VariantValues { get; set; }


}
```

[error img here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2Zx1.png)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. I suspect that something else is going on that's causing an odd diagnosis. (Or perhaps `productVariantViewModels` is a property throwing an exception - we can't tell without more information.)

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for your review! I edit the question.

Comment: That's not really a [mcve]. I can't copy/paste it into a new project and reproduce the probem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put the value in the list, it is not initialized and therefore `null`. This is causing your Null Exception.

You must first initialize the list with `new List<ProductVariantViewModel>(value)`.

And you should check if `ViewBag` or `ViewBag.ProductVariantViewModels` is `null`.

Try this:

```
(ViewBag?.ProductVariantViewModels != null)
    List<ProductVariantViewModel> productVariantViewModels = List<ProductVariantViewModel>(ViewBag.ProductVariantViewModels);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    
    List<ProductVariantViewModel> productVariantViewModels = new List<ProductVariantViewModel>();
    productVariantViewModels = ViewBag.ProductVariantViewModels;
    }
    
    ...
    ...
    ...
    
                                   
     if (productVariantViewModels != null)
     {
         foreach (var item in productVariantViewModels)
         {
    
            ...
    
         }
     }
```